# Storing nested objects in React State

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails-5, webpacker

I'm getting a json from an endpoint which looks like this:

```
{"section":{"name":"name","subsections":[
 {"name":"one","snippets":[{"title":"title","body":"body"}]},
 {"name":"two","snippets":[{"title":"title","body":"body"}]}]
}}
```

This is how I get the data:

```
fetchData() {
  axios.get('/api/data')
  .then(response => {
    this.setState({
      section: response.data.section
    })
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.fetchData();
}
```

But when I call `this.state.section.subsections[0]` I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

I know that the `subsections` is an array, but on getting the elements from it. I get an error. Would anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Edit:

I want to access the state in the render method. I can access `this.state.section.name`, I can also print `this.state.section.subsections` on the console. But whenever I try to access the elements using `this.state.section.subsections[0]` I get an error.

Comment: You are fetching the data in `componentDidMount` and accessing it where? Because `componentDidMount` is the last lifecycle hook that gets executed. Why not try to fetch the data in `componentWillMount` ?

Comment: I’m accessing it in render() method.

Comment: `componentDidMount` gets invoked after `render` method. Try fetching the data in `componentWillMount` and it could work.

Comment: @Nandu i tried. Didn’t work. I’ve just edited the question, please have a look.

Comment: First check if the data is coming as expected then add a check for subsections like `if (this.state.section.subsections) { //execute stuff }`. The only possibility I can think of is that the ajax request is not yet fulfilled by the time render method is called. Once the state is set, render will get called again with the complete response.

Comment: Since, I'm using `componentDidMount` I feel that the first time it renders, the `section` is not defined. I added a `if else` in my render and changed `componentDidMount` to `componentWillMount`. Now everything works.

Comment: Glad it worked!

Answer (score 2):

You might be trying to access data before it's available,

Try this :

```
this.setState({
    section: response.data.section
},() => {
    console.log('After state set :' ,this.state.section.subsections[0]);
});
```

If you get the `console.log` here , the issue is as I explained above , and if not then you need to `console.log(this.state.section)` and check the output

---

**First Solution :**

Provide default empty array from render

```
render(){
   const subsections = this.state.section.subsections || [];
   return(...)
}
```

**Second Solution :**

Provide default empty array from reducer as initial state

Comment: I can get `this.state.section` printed on the console. Only when I try to access the elements in the render method, I get the error.

Answer (score 1):

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined` occurs when you try to retrieve a property from an `undefined` variable.

Essentially, the console is trying to tell you that `this.state.section.subsections == undefined`, therefore you cannot call for `undefined[0]`.

You might want to check whether or not `this.state.section.subsections` exists before polling it for variables.

ie.

```
if (this.state.section.subsections) {

  // Exists.
  console.log(this.state.section.subsections)

} else {

  // Undefined.
  console.log(this.state.section.subsections)

}
```